# Linux / Bash, using ps -o to get process by specific name?

Tags: linux, bash, process

I am trying to use the ps -o command to get just specific info about processes matching a certain name. However, I am having some issues on this, when I try to use this even to just get all processes, like so, it just returns a subset of what a normal `ps -ef` would return (it doesn't return nearly the same number of results so its not returning all running processes)

```
ps -ef -o pid,time,comm
```

I want to try something like this (below) but incorporate the ps -o to just get specific info from it (just the PID)

```
ps -ef |grep `whoami`| grep firefox-bin
```

Any advice is appreciated as to how to do this properly, thanks

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This will get you the PID of a process by name:

```
pidof name
```

Which you can then plug back in to ps for more detail:

```
ps -p $(pidof name)
```

Comment: `pgrep` can also be used, but there are some differences in the way they work. For example, on my system running apache2, `pidof` will find "apache2" but not "apache" while `pgrep` will find it either way.

Comment: OS X people: `brew install pidof`

Comment: `pidof` is not standardized by POSIX and is therefore not guaranteed, as evidenced by OS X not having `pidof`.

Answer (score 30):

This is a bit old, but I guess what you want is: ps -o pid -C PROCESS_NAME, for example:

```
ps -o pid -C bash
```

EDIT: Dependening on the sort of output you expect, `pgrep` would be more elegant. This, in my knowledge, is Linux specific and result in similar output as above. For example:

```
pgrep bash
```

Comment: `pgrep` is not Linux specific, as it was introduced with Solaris and was later reimplemented under Linux and *BSDs.

Comment: pgrep is the best thing I've ever seen in my entire life. gj h7

Answer (score 13):

```
ps -fC PROCESSNAME
```

ps and grep is a dangerous combination -- grep tries to match everything on each line (thus the all too common: grep -v grep hack). ps -C doesn't use grep, it uses the process table for an exact match. Thus, you'll get an accurate list with: ps -fC sh rather finding every process with sh somewhere on the line.

Comment: This doesn't work on mac though. Mac doesn't seem to use `-C` in the same way, do you know how to do this on mac? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you need to grep the process by name - in that case:

```
ps aux | grep simple-scan
```

Example output:

```
simple-scan  1090  0.0  0.1   4248  1432 ?        S    Jun11   0:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, much late to the party, but I'll add here that if you wanted to capture processes with names identical to your search string, you could do

`pgrep -x PROCESS_NAME`

> ```
> -x          Require an exact match of the process name, or argument list if -f is given.
>              The default is to match any substring.
> ```

This is extremely useful if your original process created child processes (possibly zombie when you query) which prefix the original process' name in their own name and you are trying to exclude them from your results. There are many UNIX daemons which do this. My go-to example is **ninja-dev-sync**.