# Signal when mysqld_safe finishes launching

Tags: mysql

In my deployment script, I run a script to set up my database after I run `mysqld_safe`. But when the database setup runs, there is no `mysql` process running yet. How can I make sure to run the database setup script only after the `mysql` process is running?

Here's the script:

```
mysqld_safe >/tmp/spot.mysql.out 2>/tmp/spot.mysql.err &
mysql -u root < setup.sql
```

Comment: Why do you bring it to background then?

Comment: `mysqld_safe` is a process that doesn't exit, so if I didn't background it, by script would never run.

Comment: What exit code does it return when `mysql` server doesn't run yet? What if you combine the command run + loop + sleep and check the exit code?

Comment: The error is `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` Could you describe what you mean by run + loop + sleep?

Comment: show the `echo $?`. If it's non zero - just perform it once again in a loop PS: it's so weird that on the target server mysql doesn't run and that you have to start it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways. If you have `pidof` on your system (check with `which pidof`), then [you could use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790895/linux-bash-using-ps-o-to-get-process-by-specific-name):

```
mysqld_safe >/tmp/spot.mysql.out 2>/tmp/spot.mysql.err &
while ! pidof mysql > /dev/null
do
    sleep 5
done
mysql -u root < setup.sql
```

I don't know exactly how long you need `mysqld_safe` to run, but, the way you have it start, it will probably die due to a `SIGHUP` when your shell exits. To avoid that, [make it ignore SIGHUP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and):

```
nohup mysqld_safe >/tmp/spot.mysql.out 2>/tmp/spot.mysql.err &
while ! pidof mysql > /dev/null
do
    sleep 5
done
mysql -u root < setup.sql
```

Comment: Is this standard practice or is it considered a bad hack?

Comment: @Rose Perrone: the standard practice is to have all the services running before you run your script.

Comment: Manually running mysqld is not a standard practice in the first time.

Comment: @Rose Perrone: you run it as your operating system daemon/service

Comment: This script worked locally, but when I ran it in my `LXC` container, it didn't. As another solution, I inserted this line between the `mysqld_safe` and database setup to give the `mysqld_safe` time to launch: `apt-get install -y net-tools`.

Comment: @RosePerrone: depending how you configured the script to run from your container, your `PATH` may be different in the container and it may not include `pidof`. You could check this hypothesis by having your script `echo $PATH` or run `which pidof`. On my machine, `pidof` is in `/sbin`. It would be interesting to know the exact error before guessing further.

Comment: `which pidof` returns `/bin/pidof`

Comment: Then my guess as to what might have gone wrong was, well, wrong. What is the error that you were facing in your container? That is, if you care to troubleshoot.